# MySQL and LIKE comparison with %

Tags: mysql, sql-like

If someone passes a `'%'` to a field that compares in my sql with `su.username LIKE CONCAT('%', email ,'%'))` it returns all rows.  It ends up looking like `su.username LIKE CONCAT('%%%')`. Can I get around this in anyway without filtering out the `'%'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean you want to escape the `%` so it matches a literal `%` instead of anything.

In that case, you just need:

```
... su.username LIKE CONCAT('%',REPLACE(email,'%','\\%'),'%')
```

Comment: I have alot of fields that do this.  Should I handle it in code or in the SP?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the %, so it literally matches '%'

```
select * from mytable
where mycol like '%\%%';
```