# Escape Certain Characters On Model Property in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Can I create an attribute that will let me modify the value of it in my ASP.NET MVC Model?  It relates to this question below where '%' is being sent to the database, but I would like a generic way to escape certain characters with the data comes from the UI.  I know you can validate properties, but can you modify them on the SET?

[MySQL and LIKE comparison with %](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059414/mysql-and-like-comparison-with)

```
[Clean]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[Clean]
public string LastName{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this have a lot of value over just calling a clean method in the setter for each property?  I worry that even if this were possible, it would introduce a lot of complexity depending on what the expected behavior was.

My suggestion is to just make a function and call it from the setter instead.

Comment: I have alot of models and decorating it with an attribute would be preferred, but yes I may go with a static method that does it inside each property.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Attribute should be at the class level to get access to this class properties

Lets say :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class ClearAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private string[] wantedProperties;

    public ClearAttribute(params string[] properties)
    {
        wantedProperties = properties;
    }

    public override object TypeId
    {
        get { return new object(); }
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = value.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            if (wantedProperties.Contains(property.Name))
            {
                var oldValue = property.GetValue(value, null).ToString();
                var newValue = oldValue + "Anything you want because i don't know a lot about your case";
                property.SetValue(value, newValue, null);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the usage should be:

```
[Clear("First")]
public class TestMe{
   public string First {get; set;}
   public string Second {get; set;}
}
```

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create a **Custom Model Binder** and override the `SetProperty` method to do the clean up.

```
public class CustomModelBinder: DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void SetProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, object value)
    {
        if (propertyDescriptor.Attributes.Contains(new Clean()) && propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            value = value != null ? ((string)value).Replace("%", "") : value;
        }

        base.SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, value);
    }
}
```

You can employ any of these options to use your custom model binder.

**Registering the custom binder for a particular model in Global.asax.cs**

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyModel), new CustomModelBinder());
```

**Registering the custom binder in action parameter**

```
public ActionResult Save([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomModelBinder))]MyModel myModel)
{
}
```

**Registering the custom binder as the default model binder.**

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CustomModelBinder();
```